# Engine yard ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, engineyard

i am deploying rails 3.2.6 application to engineyard from `CLI`

When i run command

```
ey deploy -e staging
```

following error occurs

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions into the /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory.
```

any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using RVM? How did you install the `engineyard` gem? It appears that you may be trying to use the system Ruby in which case you may want to try `sudo ey deploy`.

Evan